# VBA userform textbox Set up last modified value as default value in Texbox

Tags: excel, vba

appreciated if I can get a help, I am trying to find the solution for my userform, where I have default text in textbox which needs to be circulated to 50 people to use. Textbox has statement with name, challenge: I cant create 50 userform modifying their name. so I am thinking is there any way that they update the statement along with name and sets that textbox as default one, untill it's changed from user.

Answer (score 1):

Ryan,

This should do the trick.
[image]

If you need the full name you could setup a table of User Names and Full Names then do a Vlookup on the User Name to retrieve the Full Name and place it in the textbox.

HTH